# How can I extract all the text inside a div with child tag?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to grave all the text inside a div with the existing format in the website. How can I extract them in Scrapy.

```
<div class="JobDescriptionContainer">
  <div>
    <div>
      <p>
        Posted: 21/09/2022
        <br />
        Closing Date: 21/10/2022
        <br />
        Job Type: Permanent - Full Time
        <br />
        Youth Off The Streets is a not-for-profit youth organisation that
        provides safety.
      </p>
      <h2><b>Description</b></h2
      <p>This is paragraph 2</p>
      <ui>
        <li>List 1</li>
        <li>List 2</li>
      </ui>
      <p>This is another paragraph</p>
      <div>This is from div</div>     
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to scrape all the text inside the parent div with id jobDescriptioncontainer. I code the following to do so but it is giving me all the text with inside an array. **I want the format that are showing in the website** Can anyone please help me?

```
" ".join(response.xpath('//*[@id="JobDescriptionContainer"]/div/div//text()').extract())
```

Output:

```
'''
['Posted: 21/09/2022', 'Closing Date: 21/10/2022', 'Job Type: Permanent - Full Time', 'Youth Off The Streets is a not-for-profit youth organisation that provides safety.', 'Description', 'This is paragraph 2', 'List 1', 'List 2', 'This is another paragraph', 'This is from div'] 
'''
```

Comment: `JobDescriptionContainer` is a class not an id attribute...   Also it isn't really clear what you expect the output to look like

Comment: Ok with selecting id by xpath response.xpath('//*[@id="JobDescriptionContainer"]/div/div//text()').extract()) . I want to grab all the texts inside the div with existing format.

Comment: What does with existing format mean?

Comment: You can try the below selector to extract all the text inside the div as one string. `sel.xpath("normalize-space(//*[@class='JobDescriptionContainer'])").get()`